# How to rewrite the PDE of a CDF as a SDE of r.v?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I wanted to describe the time-evolution of a probability density function (PDF) which converge to a dirac distribition centered at $\mu$, denoted as $\delta_\mu(x)$. To achieve that, I used the inverse function of the cumulative distribution function (CDF), the quantile function, denoted $Q(p)$. I tried the differential eq:

$${\partial Q\over\partial t}=\mu-Q $$

After solve it:

$$Q=\mu+e^{-t}(Q_0-\mu)$$

Then, applying the fact that $\Bbb E[X^k]=\int_{[0,1]}Q^k dp $
$$\Bbb E[X_t^k]=\int_0^1 Q^k dp=\int_0^1 \left(\mu+e^{-t}(Q_0-\mu)\right)^k\ dp $$
then by dominated convergence theorem, I can take the limit inside the integral, given that $Q\to\mu$ as $t\to\infty$ for all $p$...

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\Bbb E[X_t^k]=\int_0^1 \lim_{t\to\infty} \left(\mu+e^{-t}(Q_0-\mu)\right)^k\ dp $$

$$=\int_0^1 \mu ^k\ dp=\mu ^k $$

Now, to work back with the CDF, we can invert Q, or use the fact that:

$${\partial Q\over \partial t}=\psi(x)\phi(t)\Rightarrow {\partial F\over \partial t}=-\psi(x)\phi(t){\partial F\over \partial x} $$

where $\psi$ and $\phi$ are function of $x$ and $t$, and $F$ is the CDF of r.v X.
So the PDE which describe the time-evolution of any CDF to the CDF of the dirac distribution is:

$${\partial F\over \partial t}=(x-\mu){\partial F\over \partial x} $$
and for the time-evolution of the PDF, we differentiate with respect $x$.

$${\partial \over\partial x}{\partial F\over \partial t}={\partial \over \partial x}
\left((x-\mu){\partial F\over \partial x}\right)$$

$${\partial f\over \partial t}=f+(x-\mu){\partial f\over \partial x} $$

where $f$ is the PDF of r.v X.

The solution of that PDE is:

$$e^{t}f_0(\mu+e^{t}(x-\mu))$$

where $f_0$ is the initial distribution.
Now, my question is how you can describe the same convergence of all distribution to a dirac distribution, using the lenguage of SDE?

My attempt is to describe the PDE $\partial_t Q=-Q$ as

$$dX_t = -X_t dt $$

because $Q(p)=x$

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Do you have some specific density function in mind, that you want to prove convergence to Dirac delta?

Comment: Or are you asking for an example? A simple example is any approximation to the Dirac delta eg. $$g_{\epsilon}(x):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\epsilon}}e^{-(x-\mu)^{2}/2\epsilon}.$$ This can be used as a pdf for variable $X_{\epsilon}$ i.e. $$P[X_{\epsilon}>t]=\int_{t}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\epsilon}}e^{-(x-\mu)^{2}/2\epsilon}dx.$$

Comment: @ThomasKojar i edited the question and explained better. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your question still doesn't make sense.